# Powershell unexpected output with $_. in string

Tags: powershell

When running the below snippet of script

```
Get-ADComputer  -Filter '*'| ForEach-Object { 
    Write-output "testing $_.DnsHostName"
    #Do more with $_
}
```

I get:

```
testing CN=CO-ID96407D,OU=Contoso Computers,OU=Contoso Organisation,DC=contoso.DnsHostName
```

But what I am expecting is

```
testing CO-ID96407D.contoso
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here, I just want to output the `DnsHostName` member of `$_` but it appears to be just outputting the default output member of an `AD-Computer` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a subexpression in a string therefore you have to wrapp it in `$(...)`:

```
Write-output "testing $($_.DnsHostName)"
```

Or you can use a format string:

```
Write-output "testing {0}" -f $_.DnsHostName
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Write-output "testing $($_.DnsHostName)"
```